# Obtener el ultimo ID de una tabla 1 y insertarlo en una tabla 2 de un mismo registro en PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Buen dia tengo 2 tablas relacionadas donde hago un registro, no estoy obteniendo el id de la primera tabla:

```html
<?php
$connectid = mysql_connect("localhost","root",""); 
//selecciono la base de datos a utilizar 
mysql_select_db("dental_klin",$connectid); 
//Sentencia de inserción del elemento 
$id_cliente = $_POST['id_cliente'];
$actividad = $_POST['actividades'];
$total = $_POST['total_a_pagar']; 
$pago = $_POST['pago']; 
$debe = $_POST['pago_pendiente']; 
$tipoPago = $_POST['tipo_pago']; 
$estadoPago = $_POST['estado_pago'];
date_default_timezone_set('America/Mexico_City'); 
$date_added=date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
$ssql = "INSERT INTO consultas (id_cliente, actividades) "."values ('$id_cliente','$actividad')"; 
//lo inserto en la base de datos 
if (mysql_query($ssql,$connectid)){ 
    //recibo el último id
    $ultimo_id = mysql_insert_id($connectid); 
    $consulta_2="insert into pagos_consulta (total_a_pagar,a_pagar,debe,tipo_pago,status_pago, date,Id_consulta) "." values('$total','$pago','$debe','$tipoPago','$estadoPago','$date_added','$ultimo_id')";
?>
```

Alguien que me pudiera ayudar, me registra todos los datos del formulario menos el id_consulta que se crea automaticamente al insertar los datos en la primera tabla?

Quedo atento a sus comentarios y pronta solucion.

Comment: No te faltaria volver a llamar a mysql_query($consulta_2,$connectid) para que haga el 2do insert??

Comment: La extensión mysql de php quedo obsoleta y fue eliminada en php7 en favor de MySQLi y PDO. Igualmente indicar que tu código es vulnerable a inyección SQL.

Comment: No me afecta devido que el sistema sera local no estara en red,

Comment: Dariel ya lo intente y nada.

Answer (score 1):

Hazlo sin la variable de conexión

```
$ultimo_id = mysql_insert_id(); 
echo "Ultimo ID: " .$ultimo_id; //verificar si entrega el ID insertado
```

Comment: Buen dia cesar ya lo modifique de esa manera y no me inserta nada,

Comment: Javier, envíame el script de creación de la tabla para hacer una prueba